# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^{2n}}~dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^{2n}}~dx$$

Based on experimentation on WolframAlpha, it would seem that the value converges to a number close to 1.68294... So I have two questions: 1) How would I show this sequence converges at all and 2) is the value that the sequence converges to expressible in terms of a series or other fundamental constants etc., or is it just an irrational value that must be taken for what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac {\cos x} {1+x^{2n}} \, dx \to \int_{-1}^{1}  \cos x \, dx$ , $\int_{-\infty} ^{-1} \frac {\cos x} {1+x^{2n}} \, dx \to 0$ and $\int_{1} ^{\infty } \frac {\cos x} {1+x^{2n}} \, dx \to 0$ so the limit is $\int_{-1}^{1}  \cos x \, dx=\sin 1 - \sin (-1)=2\sin 1$. For justifying the second and third limits use the fact that $\frac 1 {1+x^{2n}} \leq \frac 1 {1+x^{2n}}$ and apply DCT.

Comment: Why does $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac {\cos x} {1+x^{2n}} \, dx \to \int_{-1}^{1}  \cos x \, dx$?

Comment: @MilesDavis: Because if $|x|<1 $ then $x^n \to 0$. (I missed that in my now deleted comment.)

Comment: But why are you allowed to interchange the limit and integration operations?

Comment: Write it as $2\int_0^{1} \frac {\cos x} {1+x^{2n}} \, dx$ and note that the integrand is bounded by 2$

Comment: Sorry, there was no need for the first step in my previous comment. The integrand is bounded by $2$ and you can use bounded convergence theorem.